# Font-Awesome not loading font, only loading css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have a static website and I tried adding font-awesome. I already have bootstrap and jquery.

On firefox it displays a weird symbol, on chrome it displays nothing. Resources shows the font-awesome css. But it does not show the fonts.  Resources -> fonts -> does not contain a fontawesome font. I looked at the directory structure/filenames and it checks out.

```
<link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="amara.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="f-a/css/font-awesome.min.css">



  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>s</li>
  </ul>
```

Only error that I get is :

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery-1.10.2.js:5374
```

Does anyone know what could possibly be the issue?

Comment: What if you remove the `s` in the `i` tag?

Comment: still doesn't work after I remove s. Also it is hosted locally jake

Comment: Are you sure all CSS has loaded correctly? They seem to be coming from everywhere.

Comment: try using font awesome's copy. put `<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">` in your `head`, remove your local version and see if that works.

Comment: CDN doesn't work either. I tried already. : / just tried again. still no. also yeah the CSS has loaded. but for some reaosn the fonts have not

Comment: I wish. It is just static html. No framework, no language, just browser interpreted.

Comment: try using the CDN, but add `http:` to the beginning of the href. that should work locally in a static html file containing just the html you provided. I included bootstrap via CDN too. without the `http:` it breaks locally (see answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is bootstrap stylesheet that is floating right and adding margin to it...

I just created this fiddle to show you what i mean

http://jsfiddle.net/fj5vj/2/

now if you add in some styles to override bootstrap you will see it now

http://jsfiddle.net/fj5vj/1/

```
 .pull-right {float:none !important}
 .navbar-nav {margin:0 !important}
```

And the last fiddle i removed the booptstrap style sheet just so you can see it

http://jsfiddle.net/fj5vj/3/

Comment: Ok cool this should do the trick looks like you were on the same path that i was for this

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue if OP's icons don't work globally. your first fiddle's problem is tied to the parent `ul` style, not the `i` element itself. if OP isn't getting *any* icons, this can't be the answer. it could very well be the problem though.

Comment: wrap it in a bootstrap `container` div or any sort of clear, and your first fiddle works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/fj5vj/7/

Answer (score 1):

the following should work locally in chrome (floated to upper right):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>s</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

without the `http:` it won't work locally:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css"
```